# How to change only the maximum value of a group in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataset

```
Item Count
A    60
A    20
A    21
B    33
B    33
B    32
```

Code to reproduce:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['A', 60],
    ['A', 20],
    ['A', 21],
    ['B', 33],
    ['B', 33],
    ['B', 32],
], 
    columns=['Item', 'Count'])
```

Suppose I have to Change only the maximum value of each group of "Item" column by adding 1.

the output should be like this:

```
Item Count New_Count
A    60    61
A    20    20
A    21    21
B    33    34
B    33    34
B    32    32
```

I tried `df['New_Count']=df.groupby(['Item'])['Count'].transform(lambda x: max(x)+1)` but all the values in "Count" was replaced by max value of each group +1.

```
Item Count New_Count
A    60    61
A    20    61
A    21    61
B    33    34
B    33    34
B    32    34
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html):

```
idx = df.groupby("Item")["Count"].idxmax()
df["New_Count"] = df["Count"]
df.loc[idx, "New_Count"] += 1
```

This will only increment the first occurrence of th maximum in each group.
If you want to increment all the maximum values in the case of a tie, you can use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) instead. Just replace the first line above with:

```
idx = df.groupby("Item")["Count"].transform(max) == df["Count"]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`idxmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) to get the idx of the maximum for each group, and increment only these items, like this:

```py
max_idxs = df.groupby(['Item'])['Count'].idxmax()
df['New_Count']=df['Count'] # copy entire column
df['New_Count'][max_idxs]+=1 # increment only the maximum item for each group by 1
```

Comment: it works but if there are 2 or more same maximum values then it only changes 1 values.

Comment: your code trigger a error messege `SettingWithCopyWarning`

Comment: @YubrajBhusal I would suggest adding such a case to your question to make the requirement clear. You can use `transform` for this, take a look at my edit to see how.

Comment: Terry you're so right, my pandas is a little rusty :P @Dan's answer is perfect, should be accepted.

Comment: @Dan thanks for suggestion. I edited it according to requirements

Answer (score 5):

Here's another way not using groupby but using `duplicated`

```
df.loc[~df.sort_values('Count', ascending=False).duplicated('Item'), 'Count'] += 1
```

Output:

```
  Item  Count
0    A     61
1    A     20
2    A     21
3    B     34
4    B     33
5    B     32
```

Answer (score 1):

to change the value in all the maximum values ​​that are repeated you will need `.groupby()`, `.join()` and `np.where()`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
['A', 60],
['A', 60],
['A', 20],
['A', 21],
['B', 21],
['B', 33],
['B', 34],
], columns=['Item', 'Count'])

s = df.groupby('Item')['Count'].max().rename('newCount')
df = df.set_index('Item').join(s).reset_index()
df['newCount'] = np.where(df['Count'] != df['newCount'], df['Count'], (df['newCount'] + 1))
df.head(10)
#output
    Item    Count   newCount
0   A       60      61
1   A       60      61
2   A       20      20
3   A       21      21
4   B       21      21
5   B       33      33
6   B       34      35
```

## Edit

We can replace the `.join()` with a `.transform()` as suggested by @Dan

```
df['newCount'] = df.groupby('Item')['Count'].transform('max')
df['newCount'] = np.where(df['Count'] != df['newCount'], df['Count'], (df['newCount'] + 1))
#output
    Item    Count   newCount
0   A       60      61
1   A       60      61
2   A       20      20
3   A       21      21
4   B       21      21
5   B       33      33
6   B       34      35
```

Comment: You could probably use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) instead of having to do a separate join.

Comment: @Dan Thanks for the sugestion mate :)